# mysql speed up query in table with 500,000 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with about 530,000 rows in it, and increasing by about 5,000 - 10,000 a day.

Currently, I have this query running, and it takes about 1.1 to 1.8 seconds to complete, which would be okay, but the query is being ran 6 times, which really slows down page load.

```
$q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5` FROM `table` WHERE `col6`='".$_SESSION['name']."' AND `col7`=".$i."");
```

$i is a constant increasing from 1 -> 6.

No partitioning, simply because I'm really unsure how to do it.

```
col1 - VARCHAR 255 INDEX   
col2 - VARCHAR 3
col3 - INT 11 INDEX
col4 - INT 11 INDEX
col5 - INT 11  
col6 - VARCHAR 255 INDEX
col7 - INT 1
```

If any more information is needed, I can provide.

If anyone has any suggestions how to make the query faster, that would be wonderful.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you please provide the full schema for the table?

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this. You have some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the query once, but use `order by` on `col7`

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`
FROM `table`
WHERE `col6`='session_name'
ORDER BY `col7`
```

Personally, I would just index `col6` as it is the main filter column used for the lookup in this query. Any other index required would depend upon other uses for the table, and which `col` is your PK.

An index on `col7` would be almost superfluous, as there are only 6 possible values it could be - it replaces `$i` in a `for` loop iteration in the original question.

Assuming that the result set would only give 1 row per value of `col7` then `5 columns * 6 rows` makes for a very small in-memory sort for the database to do.

See discussion below for more indexing options.

Comment: This worked brilliantly! Thank you so much. Is it possible to explain why it worked?

Comment: @Stewart who knows. But yeah, removing 5 out of 6 queries and also a `WHERE` clause on an unindexed column... about as good as he could do I would think.

Comment: This answer isn't complete without mentioning which columns need to be covered with index

Comment: @Stewart: I don't see your point :-( The answer for the question about speeding up **SHOULD** contain advice about required indexes.

Comment: " I would index col6 and col7" --- how exactly? As 2 separate indexes?

Comment: @zerkms why don't you just provide your own answer, seeing as your perfectionism isn't impinging upon me :)

Comment: @Stewart: I don't see a reason for that (as soon as yours covers most part of what should be said). I'd better helped you to improve your answer and upvote it

Comment: Ok, well you come across as critical rather than helpful. If you have a recommendation to make, I'll add it to the answer if that's the way you want to do it.

Comment: @Stewart: I think it should be mentioned that `(col6, col7)` should be a composite index

Comment: Why would `col6` and `col7` be a composite index? There may be other lookups for which the table is used. Generally I would want a compelling reason for a composite key. How much performance improvement are we talking compared with 2 individual indexes?

Comment: The queries used on said table is in the thousands, and very few using those two columns together. Anyways, like I said above, can anyone give a reasoning for why using ORDER BY worked so well in this case?

Comment: @Stewart: it should be composite because mysql can only use one index per table (with very rare exceptions, not the case here) used in from/join clause. So as soon as you have them separated, `col6` will be used to filter then the whole result set will be sorted in memory. Whereas if you had a composite index - then the result set would be **already sorted** so no additional sort would be required.

Comment: @Stewart, most of the time, MySQL can use only one index per table in a given query. If you define single-column indexes in this case, it will probably choose the index on `col6` and ignore the index on `col7`. This will help, of course, but it will do a "filesort" of the rows matching the session name. By using an index on `(col6, col7)`, in that specific order, then the query fetches rows in pre-sorted order and can skip the filesort. See my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

Comment: The result set has a max of `6` rows. I think sorting in memory will be fast.

Comment: @Stewart: the table size is just 500k it fits the memory, so even indexing for `col6` isn't necessary. Is it your exact point? PS: not sure where you get that 6 rows stats.

Comment: Yeah, we know from the OP's description that there are *at least* six distinct values in col7 (he's querying for values 1-6 but there could be other values), but we don't know that there is only one occurrence of each of these value per session.

Comment: @Bill - good point. I had assumed that the result set would only give 1 row per value of `col7`

Comment: Anyway, even an in-memory filesort of a small result set has more overhead than not doing a filesort at all. We don't know what kind of data we're talking about, so we can't make a conclusion about how much of an advantage the composite index would give. But I don't know why you are reluctant to create composite indexes, these are common and necessary.

Comment: It's really just the unknownness of the rest of the schema (but with `col6` being a `varchar` and `col7` being `int 1`) and the queries that will be run. In the end, after this long discussion, and looking again at the OP's original question, I chose: "Keep It Simple".